# React Navigation Typescript narrow route params properly with 2 different param type options

Tags: typescript, react-navigation

I am creating a React Native Expo app using React Navigation. I am trying to create a screen that will accept 2 different types of props, depending on whether I am adding or editing the screen.

I have the code and it works. However, I continually get a "Property does not exist on type" error. I'm still new to typescript, so my frustration of "I know the property doesn't exist on the type, that is why I'm trying to narrow!" is high. How do I get the error to go away?

Here is the code I'm using to narrow:

```
type POIScreenProps = StackNativeScreenProps<"Point of Interest">;

export default function PointOfInterest({ navigation, route }: POIScreenProps) {
  const poiObj: POIObj = route.params?.poi ?? {
    trailId: null,
    pointsOfInterestId: null,
    description: null,
    image: null,
    isActive: true,
    latitude: route.params.currentLocation.latitude,
    longitude: route.params.currentLocation.longitude,
  };
```

So `route.params?.poi` gives me this error:

> Property 'poi' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ poi: POIObj; } | {
> handleSetPoI(value: POIObj): void; currentLocation:
> LocationObjectCoords; }>'.

And I get a similar error with `route.params.currentLocation`.

I set up my StackParamList like this:

```
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { LocationObjectCoords } from "expo-location";
import { POIObj } from "./POIObj";

export type StackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Admin: undefined;
  "Trail Screen": { trailID: number | null } | undefined;
  "Point of Interest":
    | {
        // view/edit trail
        poi: POIObj;
      }
    | {
        // add trail        
        handleSetPoI(value: POIObj): void;
        currentLocation: LocationObjectCoords;
      };
};

export type StackNativeScreenProps<T extends keyof StackParamList> =
  NativeStackScreenProps<StackParamList, T>;

declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface ParamList extends StackParamList {}
  }
}
```

Am I approaching this incorrectly? Should I just make all of the parameters optional and in a single type definition? That doesn't seem appropriate because those are two distinct options.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I ended up going a different direction on this. You can't pass functions through params when using react navigation. I ended up just making the remaining items optional and closing this out,.

Answer (score 1):

This is not React-Navigation Typescript problem . This error is related to Union Types in Typescript . Please check the docs abut [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)